# How to match Weka logistic regression prediction with manual calculation through spreadsheet?

Tags: weka, logistic-regression

I am trying to recalculate predictions of a logistic regression using excel spreadsheet from the coefficients I obtained in Weka.

The formula being used is : P =  1/(1+EXP(-1*(INTERCEPT + Coeff1*Variable1 + Coeff2*Variable2+Coeff3*Variable3+Coeff4*Variable4)))

Intercept and Coeff1,Coeff2,Coeff3,Coeff4 are obtained from Weka output.

Variable1,Variable2,Varibale3,Variable4 are values of independent variables.

The difference in prediction between Weka and manual calculation in excel spreadsheet is small but do exist. (0.5005 versus 0.4900) .

My question is : 
1. Currently the logistic regression coefficients are of 4 decimal places only. Is there a way to increase the precision of co-coefficients to six or higher decimal places to exact prediction ?
2.Any other way to match it ?